# How can I make RELATIVE_PATH that added in android Q backward compatible?

Tags: android, storage, media, mediastore, scoped-storage

According to the docs the RELATIVE_PATH
Added in API level 29
public static final String RELATIVE_PATH
Relative path of this media item within the storage device where it is persisted. For example, an item stored at /storage/0000-0000/DCIM/Vacation/IMG1024.JPG would have a path of DCIM/Vacation/.

How can I organize my media files that being inserted to MediaStore on Android prior to Android Q
Afaik: `PRIMARY_DIRECTORY` doesn't work
  `put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.PRIMARY_DIRECTORY, relativePath)` according to the docs it has been removed

```
/**
 * The primary directory name this media exists under. The value may be
 * {@code NULL} if the media doesn't have a primary directory name.
 *
 * @removed
 * @deprecated Replaced by {@link #RELATIVE_PATH}.
 */
@Column(Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_STRING)
@Deprecated
public static final String PRIMARY_DIRECTORY = "primary_directory";
```

Comment: "How can I organize my media files that being inserted to MediaStore on Android prior to Android Q" -- use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)`, create a directory under there, and save your images using ordinary file I/O.

Comment: I just wanted to use MediaStore API using the insert method to avoid maintaining two different implementations, is there any way to do that?

Comment: No, sorry, there is not.

Comment: have you found any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just need to use `Media.DATA` below Android Q and use `Media.RELATIVE_PATH` otherwise.

FYI, I wrote a [function](https://gist.github.com/oOJohn6Oo/208e42d0d832ac0255387872bfa5519d) to achieve this.